# GitLab Continuous Integration with Laravel 5.2 Project hosted in Digital Ocean

Tags: laravel, gitlab, host, digital-ocean, gitlab-ci

Greeting

I am trying to implement the Continuous Integration in GitLab in order to automatically deploy the succeeded build code to Host in Digital Ocean. I was searching to find the solution, but still no luck.

There is some articles mentioning about that, but it's not working when I follow it

https://medium.com/teknomuslim/how-to-setup-laravel-with-gitlab-continuous-integration-5cebd6c0be64#.cyoafaxt0

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/laravel-ci-testing-with-gitlab

Do you guys have any experience about it?
Please help